# Do you keep using a compromised gmail account?

Tags: google, gmail

if you see under account info that your gmail account had suspicious activities, do you keep using the account after you beef up the security (such as changing the password)?

Comment: This question is too subjective as it is asking for everyone's opinion and not a quantifiable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's probably fine. Just to be safe, I'd also change the recovery email and phone number, review the list of authorized apps to make sure there's nothing fishy there, enable two-factor authentication, scan computers used to access the account for malware, and ask friends to be alert for anything suspicious originating from the account. You may also want to make sure your address hasn't been placed on spam blacklists.

Now if a *computer* were to be compromised, it would be a different story - I wouldn't use the computer again without an OS reinstall, or at least a thorough antivirus cleaning in the case of Windows machines. The difference is that a computer OS is sophisticated enough that there are tons of places where backdoors could be hidden to allow the attacker to re-compromise the machine, and it's difficult to know whether you've removed all of them. The same concerns don't really apply to web services like Gmail.

Comment: I would also run a search on the available mail on the account for passwords, license keys, account numbers, and anything that might have leaked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, why not? I personally has never been informed that there is suspicous activity on my account, but I'm usally very careful where I leave my email address. And I have a strong password and two factor authentication enabled.

My advice is to change password, set a **strong password**, and enable two factor authentication. And check your app passwords list to see if you have application on that list that is not anymore in use, or applications that not should be there.